# Recognizing AngularJS syntax in WebMatrix 3

Tags: web, angularjs, ide, webmatrix

I've been using WebMatrix because of nodejs and backbonejs. I've recently started to learn angular and I want webmatrix to recognize angular's syntax and stop telling me my ng's are unknown. My code works fine but its just annoying. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Technically ng-* is not a valid HTML attribute per spec, so we show an error.  Luckily Angular allows you to define your attribute using data-ng-* attributes to make them valid:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

You should be able to just use data-ng-* anywhere you're using ng-*.

Happy Coding!